# How to make sure messages are queued?

Tags: c#

I made a static class that's in charge of logging stuff into my console interface:

```
public enum LogLevel : byte
{
    Error = 0,
    Warning,
    Info,
    Connection,
    Success,
}

public static class Logger
{
    private static object sLocker = new object();

    private static readonly Dictionary<LogLevel, ConsoleColor> sLogColors = new Dictionary<LogLevel, ConsoleColor>
    {
        { LogLevel.Error,       ConsoleColor.Red        },
        { LogLevel.Warning,     ConsoleColor.Yellow     },
        { LogLevel.Info,        ConsoleColor.White      },
        { LogLevel.Success,     ConsoleColor.Green      },
        { LogLevel.Connection,  ConsoleColor.DarkGreen  },
    };

    private static readonly Dictionary<LogLevel, string> sLogNames = new Dictionary<LogLevel, string>
    {
        { LogLevel.Error,       "[Error] "      },
        { LogLevel.Warning,     "[Warning] "    },
        { LogLevel.Info,        "[Info] "       },
        { LogLevel.Success,     "[Success] "    },
        { LogLevel.Connection,  "[Connection] " },
    };

    public static void Entitle(string title)
    {
        Console.Title = title;
    }

    public static void Write(LogLevel logLevel, string format, params object[] objects)
    {
        lock (sLocker)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = sLogColors[logLevel];
            Console.Write(sLogNames[logLevel]);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.WriteLine(format, objects);
        }

        if (logLevel == LogLevel.Error)
        {
            Console.Beep();
        }
    }

    public static void Exception(Exception ex)
    {
        string exception = ex.ToString();
        string message = string.Format("[{0}]-----------------{1}{2}{1}", DateTime.Now, Environment.NewLine, exception);

        lock (sLocker)
        {
            File.AppendAllText("EXCEPTIONS.txt", message);
        }

        //Keep outside to prevent a deadlock.
        Write(LogLevel.Error, "An exception was logged{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, exception);
    }
}
```

However, I would like the messages to show one after one. By that I mean - queue them somehow. How can I achieve this with my static class?

Comment: If this class is a learning process, then fine, but is this is for something more serious, there are many and varied existing logging nuget packages that will handle all of the hard work and will have come across any problems you will encounter.

Comment: What do you want to queue them for? You're already using a `lock` to ensure that messages don't get mixed up. And have you tried the `Queue<T>` class?

Comment: Use the collection Queue. Add the items in the Queue collection using Enqueue. Define some criteria (as per the business logic), when to write to console or file from the collection Queue. Dequeue the written items from the collection.

Comment: It is utterly unclear what you are trying to achieve, be more specific. You are "logging" them to the Console, so they will be "queued" to the Console output pipe in the exact order in which you are going to call `Write`. If you want to log them to a variable in memory, for further processing, you will need to use a `List` object. Since `Queue` objects won't allow you to easily access the whole log. `List` objects are ordered lists, so each time you call `List.Add()` a new entry will be added to the end of the `List`.